# How i can use TV Channels Logos on my App

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, broadcast, http-live-streaming, iptv

I am developing an TV Channels app and i am using TV channel button to redirect on official page for watching Tv channel. I want to add Tv Channel logos on every channel link button. I want to know that can i use logos of channels on my app, or there is any restrictions or copyright issues. If this is illegal way to directly add logos or copyright issues, so how i can use logos on my app. Or is there any api that provide both streaming and logos or another way to use.  Because i've seen there are many apps that are using logos of tv channels on there apps. Like [this](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pakistan-tv/id823609928?mt=8) and [this](https://itunes.apple.com/pk/app/pakistani-tv/id503142275?mt=8)
Thanks

Comment: 1) How is this a programming question? 2) You might just check the websites of the channels, normally companies have a "media" or "press" section with stuff like logos.

Comment: I am using WebVIew beacuse i've seen on many apps they are redirect to video link? Is it right way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's non programming.